# select the first h2 before $(this) which is not in the same level as $(this)

Tags: jquery

here is a simplified version of my html

```
<ul>
    <li><h2>1/1/2014</h2></li>
    <li>
       <ul>
         <li> <div class="something">  <span class="more"> +3 </span> </div> </li>
       </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><h2>2/3/2014</h2></li>
            <ul>
                 <li> <span class="more"> +9 </span> </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is my jq code

```
$('.more').each(function(){

   var more = $(this).text();
   var date = $(this).prev('h2').text();

})
```

i want to get the immediate `h2`  before each `.more`
i've tried all the `prev` methods and `closest` but none of them works

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have an `<li>` as a child of another `<li>`.

Comment: @j08691, I don't see that he has that, he has nested ULs, which is fine.

Comment: @pedalpete `<li>

      <li><h2>2/3/2014</h2></li>`

Comment: To create the proper answer you first need to create proper HTML.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble but it's still not valid. Your `<ul>` can't contain another `<ul>`.  Ex: `<ul>
            <li><h2>2/3/2014</h2></li>
            <ul>`. It would need to be within an `<li>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.more').each(function(index, elem){
  $(elem).parents('ul').first().parent().prev().find('h2')
  // Then do whatever you want with the h2...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The h2 isn't a 'prev' or 'before' element, as it is nested within an LI.

You need to use

```
 $('.more').each(function(){

   var more = $(this).text();
   var date = $(this).parents('li').prev('li').children('h2').text();
  alert(date);

});
```

You'll need to check that the 'date' is not empty.

here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jLZww/1/